# Append arguments to docker compose test service command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to figure out a way to make a service that takes optional arguments to append to the service (or entry) command. For example:

```
  testing:
    <<: *backend
    environment:
      # Use the system rails environment or default to test
      - RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV:-test}
    command: bash -c "bundle exec rspec"
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
```

So if I run `docker-compose run testing` it will test all my specs (this much works), but I could also append arguments to specify a file and/or line numbers like `docker-compose run testing /specs/models/something.rb:33`

Edit: My goal is to reduce the amount of typing needed to test locally. Currently would take the following to specify a particular test:

`docker-compose run testing bundle exec rspec spec/models/something.rb:133`

Comment: Can you edit your `database.yml` file to point at the database running in Docker, and run `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rspec ...` from the host (without Docker)?  And then you can delete this block from the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes we have a container for the database, but this has nothing to do with my question or goal. `RAILS_ENV=test` sets the rails environment to test, which does more than just change the database used. This 'testing' is more of an example rather than the specific use case

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `entrypoint`. Setup the service such as:

```
testing:
<<: *backend
environment:
  # Use the system rails environment or default to testing
  - RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV:-test}
entrypoint: ["bundle", "exec", "rspec"]
ports:
  - '3000:3000'
```

Then to run a particular test `docker-compose run testing spec/models/something.rb:139`